# You have 6 green chips, 6 black, and 6 yellow. You randomly select a sample of 3 chips without replacement.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

You have 6 green chips, 6 black, and 6 yellow. You randomly select a sample of 3 chips without replacement. What is the probability that the sample contains at least one chip of each color?

Comment: Got it. There isn't a complete answer to that one though, what can I do?

Comment: @Q.Araham Yes there is. all of the answers are complete. all you need is a calculator then plug and chug...

Comment: Got it. Thanks for redirecting me to the question!